# I have a link to s3 bucket, when accessed it provides XML file which contains names of the bucket's contents, how can I download the entire bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Just want to know if there is an automatic way of doing it

I am looking for a tool or something

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have an access to this bucket the best way would be to use AWS CLI

e.g. [sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

There are plenty of tools to do what you desire. For example: [enter link description here](https://s3tools.org/s3cmd)

Comment: I just found the link online, will AWS CLI work in this case? Or is there anything easier?

Comment: Check out this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html